# Java Special Symbol Serialization

Tags: java, serialization, char

I wanted to know how does a primitive character is serialized in java. I serialized a class to understand how byte information is stored in java. Following is the class which I serialised.

```
public class Person implements Serializable{
    char ch = (char) 128;
    private String name = "abc" + ch;
    private int age = 11;

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age){
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

When I converted it to byte array, the value for

> "abc" + ch

was

> 97 98 99 -62 -128

I wanted to know how ch is represented by -62 -128. "abc" are represented according to their ASCII value but how is ch represented using -62 -128

Comment: strings are written in  [Modified UTF-8](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8) format, according [ObjectOutputStream.writeUTF](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String)) method's documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java strings are UTF-8 encoded in the default serialization.

You can see the full specification of UTF-8 summarized [on the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Notice that characters between 0x00 and 0x7F are stored as-is, as one byte, but characters 0x80 through 0x07FF are stored as a two-byte sequence, 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx, where the 'x' represent the sequential eleven bits used for values in that range.

Your char 128 is in that range, with bit sequence 00010000000.  So the corresponding two-byte UTF-8 sequence is 11000010 10000000, or -62, -128 if you interpret those as signed 8-bit characters.

(The Java version of UTF-8 is actually slightly different than what's on the Wiki for some special characters, but it doesn't affect this string!)